# Изменение размера запущенного activity в режиме free-form

Tags: android, kotlin

**Коротко про режим free-form**

Free-form - это режим для работы с окнами произвольной формы. [Подробнее...](https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/multi-window?hl=ru#freeform)
[image: Пример работы]
**Мой код для запуска activity в режиме free-form**

```
val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome")

var options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic()
try {
    val method: Method = ActivityOptions::class.java.getMethod("setLaunchWindowingMode", Int::class.javaPrimitiveType)
    method.invoke(options, 5)
} catch (_: Exception) {}

val windowsSize = Rect(
    0,
    0,
    resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels,
    resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
)
options = options.setLaunchBounds(windowsSize)

startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
```

Для корректной работы кода необходимо включить несколько опций в режиме разработчика

```
adb shell settings put global enable_freeform_support  1
adb shell settings put global force_resizable_activities  1
```

**Вопрос**

Как программно изменить размер окна, в котором запущено activity, без потери данных в activity (без перезапуска приложения)?

Comment: Может так? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25230864/5479247

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja Это будет работать в моем Activity. Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно изменять размер сторонних приложений